# Requiring hierarchy of directives and using parent in child scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I'd like to be able to have something similar to this:

```
<tr property="value">
  <td some-directive></td>
</tr>
```

And then in `someDirective`:

```
link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
  console.log(scope.property); // "value"
```

How is this achievable? I'm having trouble with 1) requiring the parent directive and 2) accessing it's scope. Here's what I tried (directive/property names are fake):

```
app.directive('property', function() {
  transclude: true,
  template: '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>',
  controller: function(){},
  scope: {
    property: '='
  }
});

app.directive('someDirective', function() {
  require: '^property'
  transclude: true,
  replace: true,
  scope: {
    someDirective: '='
  }
  templateUrl: 'my_template.html',
  controller: function($scope) {
    console.log($scope.property);
  }
});
```

I don't fully understand how this works. Can anyone please clarify the exact usage?

The problem I'm trying to solve is how to avoid repetitive defining of a binded property across children directives. They're all supposed to point to the same object in the controller scope, so I'd like to avoid setting on each use of the child directive, and instead only define them once on the parent. Is this possible? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with $scope.$parent.property?

Requiring directives is good if you want to share some functionalities across directives. `A` directive has a controller with useful functions that you want to use for your child directives (let's say `B` directive).

Comment: Would that be the go-to method of doing this? Also how would these be organizes: Would the parent/child have isolated scopes, and how would it work when I want to bind from the view's controller? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that it'll be so bad. But I'd rather create controllers instead of directives. Let's say you have a 'main' controller which has a state wired and which loads a user profile. It has a lot of data, and you may split those data into few different sections to make the data management readable and well separated. Then you'll create controllers which will just simply take over different data management/functions for the particular user data.

Comment: You simple do `ng-controller="userContactDetailsCtrl as ctrl"` and then inside a controller you do a shortcut: `$scope.contactDetails = $scope.parent.userData.contactDetails`;